# trying to convert Longitude Latitude via google Geolocation API with no luck

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, axios

hay guys, i'm new to JavaScript async programming, and i trying to take a file with only Longitude and Latitude and convert it to a street address

i converted my table to json file and imported the file to my little program,
after that i'm trying to go through my array and get the address from the api,
and i keep getting all sort of errors depends on my changes i do to fix the f**g thing

```
const axios = require('axios');
import * as fs from 'fs';


const getResults = async () => {
    const apiKey = 'blablabla'
    const data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("csvjson.json"));

    const getAddress = (lng,lat) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      axios.get(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${lng},${lat}&key=${apiKey}`)
      .then(response => {
        return resolve(response.data)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        return reject(error.message)
      })
    })
  }


    const newData = data.map(async item => {
    const newItem = {
        ...item,
        results_from_google: item.Longitude !== "blank" ? await getAddress(item.Longitude,item.Latitude) : 'blank'

    }

    //console.log('the results: '+ results)

    return newItem;

})

const results = await Promise.all(newData)

console.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, 2))
    console.log(results)
    fs.writeFileSync("./format-more-output.json", JSON.stringify(results, null, 2));
}

getResults()
```

my errors for now is

```
(node:16488) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Request failed with status code 400
(node:16488) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:16488) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
PS
```

thanks for the help guys

Comment: did you read the error messages? You get a `400 Bad Request` error from the server and since you rethrow the error message here: `reject(error.message)` you have a rejected promise that is not taken care of; like an error thrown that is never catched. And the 3rd message tells you that in the future the `Unhandled promise rejection` error message will be replaced by **your app crashing** *(with a non-zero exit code)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried your code out, there is only one mistake I can see, the latitude and longitude were the wrong way round, you were passing lng,lat whereas the API requires lat,lng. I suspect this is why you were getting the 400 error.

I've updated the code to handle error conditions a little better. Also I'd reconsider using inline function expressions, these make the code harder to read IMHO, maybe refactor them out!

This is working for me:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');

const getResults = async () => {
    const apiKey = API_KEY;
    const data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("csvjson.json"));

    const getAddress = (lng,lat) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log(`Getting address for ${lat}, ${lng}...`);
            axios.get(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${lat},${lng}&key=${apiKey}`)
            .then(response => {
                return resolve(response.data)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                return reject(error.message)
            })
        })
    }

    const newData = data.map(async item => {
        const newItem = {
            ...item,
            results_from_google: item.Longitude !== "blank" ? await getAddress(item.Longitude,item.Latitude) : 'blank'

        }
        return newItem;
    })

    try {
        const results = await Promise.all(newData);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, 2));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
        fs.writeFileSync("./format-more-output.json", JSON.stringify(results, null, 2));
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("An error occurred: ", error);
    }

}

getResults();
```

I'm using an input of:

**csvjson.json**

```
[
    {
        "Latitude": 34.05016083426763,
        "Longitude": -118.47179800984532
    }
]
```

And the results look like so (only showing the first lines!):

**format-more-output.json**

```
[
  {
    "Latitude": 34.05016083426763,
    "Longitude": -118.47179800984532,
    "results_from_google": {
      "plus_code": {
        "compound_code": "3G2H+37 Los Angeles, CA, USA",
        "global_code": "85633G2H+37"
      },
      "results": [
        {
          "address_components": [
            {
              "long_name": "816",
              "short_name": "816",
              "types": [
                "street_number"
              ]
            },
            {
              "long_name": "South Bundy Drive",
              "short_name": "S Bundy Dr",
              "types": [
                "route"
```

Comment: Cool, you're climbing the learning curve fast if you're only starting async Javascript programming!

Comment: You might accept the answer if it works for you. Thanks!

Comment: you sure right man , and thanks again, Even though it was a small problem, sometimes you need another set of eyes to solve a nagging problem =]